# How to use a custom function with quantile() in rollapply()

Tags: r, custom-function

I am not sure how to optimize my custom function for use within `rollapply`. I'm essentially using `.bincode` and `quantile` to number the quantile a value falls within. I realized that it makes more sense to limit the range of values used as inputs, but I'm not sure what of my code needs to be changed.

I'm assuming I need to change my output from a `mutate` call to something that returns a vector within `rollapply` or I need to add `rollapply` to my function and pass parameters to it from there....

```
libary(zoo)
libray(dplyr)

# Data
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(date = rep(seq(as.Date("2023-01-01"), as.Date("2023-01-31"), by="1 day"), each = 2),
                  player = rep(c("A", "B"), times = 31),
                  results = c(1, 1, 100, 100, sample(1:100, 58, replace = TRUE)) # ensure scores range from 1-100
                  )

# Custom function
quantile_num <- function(df, value, probs = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.95, 1), na.rm = TRUE) {

    value <- enquo(value)

    df |>
    mutate(
      quantiles = .bincode(
        !!value,
        breaks = quantile(
          !!value,
          probs = probs,
          na.rm = na.rm
        ),
        include.lowest = TRUE
      )
    )
}

# Working example
dat |>
  quantile_num(value = results)

# date             player results  quantiles
# 1  2023-01-01      A       1         1
# 2  2023-01-01      B       1         1
# 3  2023-01-02      A     100         6
# 4  2023-01-02      B     100         6
# 5  2023-01-03      A      40         2
# 6  2023-01-03      B      30         2
# 7  2023-01-04      A      94         6
# 8  2023-01-04      B      89         5
# 9  2023-01-05      A      16         1
# 10 2023-01-05      B      88         5

# Intended functionality (not working)
dat |>
  rollapply(results, width = 7, FUN = quantile_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the intended result was not shown in the question -- what was shown is what did not work so I can't be sure what is wanted but this does give a result and maybe it is what you are looking for or maybe what is wanted is to do it by player in which case a group_by can be added.

```
quantbin <- function(x, probs = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.95, 1), na.rm = TRUE) {
  .bincode(x, 
           breaks = quantile(x, probs = probs, na.rm = na.rm), 
           include.lowest = TRUE) |>
    setNames(probs)
}
      
dat |>
  mutate(as.data.frame(rollapplyr(results, 7, quantbin, fill = NA)))
```

giving

```
         date player results  0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 0.95  1
1  2023-01-01      A       1 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA NA
2  2023-01-01      B       1 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA NA
3  2023-01-02      A     100 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA NA
4  2023-01-02      B     100 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA NA
5  2023-01-03      A      31 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA NA
6  2023-01-03      B      79 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA NA
7  2023-01-04      A      51  1   1   5   5   2    4  3
8  2023-01-04      B      14  1   5   5   2   4    3  1
9  2023-01-05      A      67  5   5   1   4   2    1  3
10 2023-01-05      B      42  6   1   5   3   1    4  2
11 2023-01-06      A      50  1   6   4   1   5    2  3
12 2023-01-06      B      43  6   4   1   5   1    3  2
13 2023-01-07      A      14  5   1   6   2   4    3  1

# ...snip...
```

Comment: The formatting wasn't clear on the output so hopefully it's clearer now. I would like to emulate what I have done to create the `quantile` column, but use `rollapply` to limit the range of values used to calculate. I would like to return the quantile number for each value based on the window provided by `rollapply`. For example, row 7 would return "3" as 51 falls between the 40%-60% quantiles based on the 6 previous scores. Shown via `quantile(c(1,1,100,100,31,79,51), probs = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.95, 1), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: f <- function(x, probs = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.95, 1), na.rm = TRUE)  {...}; dat |>  mutate(newcol = rollapplyr(results, 7, f, fill = NA)) You can fill in the dots with a body that returns whatever scalar it is that you want given the inputs x, probs and na.rm and x is a numeric vector that rollapplyr will pass to it.